# Any ideas how to display divs vertically in bootstrap container?

Tags: html, css

I have these divs that are products

```
<div class="container">
<div class="product">
                            <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg"/></div>
                            <div class="description">
                                <h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">
                                <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg"/></div>
                            <div class="description">
                                <h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">
                                <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
 </div>
```

And its CSS

```
.image{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 180px;
    height: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left:.40cm;
}
.description{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}
.productname{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: 25px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.price{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #E40613;
}

.product{
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Now these are just two divs but they can be 10 or 15 through foreach loop when data is fetched from mysql

Now these divs are showing horizontally I want to have them vertically in a container with a slider, if not slider possible then how could displaying vertically be achieved?

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/bLs5tux2/4/ ?

Comment: Why doesn't it work with bootstrap container?

Comment: for bootstrap, you have to do something like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/bLs5tux2/6/

Comment: Unable to replicate - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qajYAx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `display: inline-block` to the product class. You may need to define widths as well if you have many divs.

Comment: It worked with the code you gave which I plugged into a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/br9vm4yp/

 If you have more code that affects this layout I suggest you post it